# accessing a json.parse multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have the following json :-

```
{
    "firstName": "Jhon",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "username": "jhon",
    "avatar": "localhost/uploads/avatars/default.jpg",
    "language": "ar",
    "birth_date": "2017-11-22 00:00:00",
    "weight_chart": [],
    "health_status": {
        "id": 130,
        "user_id": 258,
        "weight": 95,
        "height": 171,
    },
```

I decoded the above json

```
$user = json_decode($response);
```

Now i am able to print the firstname by using:
 $user->firstName

My questions is :-

- Can i access the json values without decoding it ?
- How can i access the "health_status" values id, weight ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is malformed, try this structure:

```
$str = '{
    "firstName": "Jhon",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "username": "jhon",
    "avatar": "localhost/uploads/avatars/default.jpg",
    "language": "ar",
    "birth_date": "2017-11-22 00:00:00",
    "weight_chart": [],
    "health_status": {
        "id": 130,
        "user_id": 258,
        "weight": 95,
        "height": 171
    }
}';

$obj = json_decode($str);
echo $obj->firstName.' - ';
echo $obj->health_status->id.' - ';
echo $obj->health_status->weight;
```

response:  `Jhon - 130 - 95`

Comment: The json i am getting is from some api web services not a json file , i cannot control the structure of the json .

Comment: @user2873860 Your JSON document in the question is malformed. If it's just a typo because you hand-wrote/edited it you should just admit/fix that so everyone can move on.